# Installing TP-Link AC1200 T4UH USB Wireless Device

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

I've downloaded the Linux drivers here: http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T4UH.html#Driver
How do I install them? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: There is probably a better way. Please edit your question to add these details from the terminal: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r`. Welcome to askubuntu. (Ref: 8812au)

Answer (score 4):

The 'driver' available on your website for the TP-Link AC1200 Model T4UH (Version V1.0) is version 150821 and is for

```
System version: Ubuntu 14.04.1
Kernel version: 3.16.0-30-generic
Gcc version:4.8.2
```

I have 16.04 Linux version 4.4.0-36-generic and gcc version 5.4.0 20160609

Running 'make' reports -

```
In file included from /home/a/Driver/include/drv_types.h:95:0,
                 from /home/a/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/a/Driver/include/hal_com.h:412:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
             ^
In file included from include/linux/compat.h:15:0,
                 from include/linux/ethtool.h:15,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:42,
                 from /home/a/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/a/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/a/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/a/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
include/linux/fs.h:2572:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
              ^
```

Contacted TP-Link who passed the buck and said that "the chip set for Archer T4UH is Realtek RTL8812AU. Github is one of the popular platforms. Please try to find out the driver from there."

Installed a package from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/base/rtl8812au-dkms).

All appears OK

Comment: For me it says `ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic is not supported`. Which kernel does it support?

Answer (score 1):

As you have downloaded the file, remember where you have downloaded.

Extract it to a file and name it Driver or any other name. For me I name it Driver.

Right click on this Driver file to take a look at properties and we can see where the file is kept so that the command can be put into terminal.

This is what I saw in the extracted file under properties when I right click it
`/home/thomas/Documents/Driver` type this command in terminal by adding a cd in front so it becomes ( remember to space after typing cd and it shall look like this:

```
cd /home/thomas/Documents/Driver
```

Type the command:

```
make
```

after the loading of the drivers type

```
sudo make install
```

At this stage, plugging in a T4U dongle should be detected and the appropriate driver loaded.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked for me too.  I also installed the package from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/base/rtl8812au-dkms

Worked just fine: download with install, reboot, lights blink, wireless networks appear, connect with passwords and all is well.  This is on a HP Z600 dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 - no problems and Ubuntu install was actually easier than installing the Windows drivers if you overlook the time it took to find this solution.  Thanks !!!!!!!

Comment: Argh!!  As of the Ubuntu and Ubuntu mate updates installed 15 May 2017 the T4UH no longer works.  To add insult to injury, the update was installed over the wifi link using the T4UH with drivers installed as per previous comment.   The driver is still there as "proprietary" but ....  Thank heavens they are dual boot machines.

Comment: This work-around is limited to situations where you can access the package on the Net using (eg) a wired connection (since by definition your T4UH wifi isn't working). Basically you do whatever updating you need, then uninstall and reinstall the driver.

Go to "Additional Drivers" (Ubuntu: Search, and Additional drivers is the first Icon; Mate: Administration> Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. The previously installed driver is shown. You get rid of it by selecting "Do not use this device" / Apply changes.  Then you go to the site above and re-install drivers [Apt Install].

Comment: This work-around process above also works after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 Mate.