# How to install TP-Link T4UH drivers [2357:010e]

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.04, realtek-wireless

This is probably a very simple issue, so sorry for bothering but I'm totally new to Ubuntu.

I have version Ubuntu 17.04.

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694152/installing-tp-link-ac1200-t4uh-usb-wireless-device) thread and downloaded [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/base/rtl8812au-dkms) file.

My biggest issue is that when I click "install" after double-clicking the .deb file, it doesn't do anything. Literally, nothing - the text doesn't even change to "installing".

I tried opening it with dpkg like propesed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904539/cant-install-deb-files-on-ubuntu-gnome-17-04) (as it appears to be similar to my case), but I keep getting dependency errors (it requires package dkms, but when downloaded dkms itself also gives me dependency errors, and at this point I feel that I'm just doing it the wrong way)).

Sadly, the USB device is currently my only option of connecting to the internet on this PC, so all the packages so far I've had to get by downloading on another device and dropping it off by USB.

`sudo lshw -class network` shows only my integrated (Ethernet port only) network adapter.

`lsusb` lists this:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:010e
```

Oh, and in case this is relevant - this installation was done with the "nomodeset xforcevesa" command, as I have gotten freezes during normal installation.

I hope that I didn't forget anything important, and thank you for help in advance.

Comment: If you have installed 17.04, you need the *zesty* packages, not *xenial*. Please try dkms from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/dkms and tell us what the missing dependencies are. The packages in xenial nor zesty for rtl8812au-dkms do *not* cover your exact device, se we will need to use another method, ideally including dkms.

Comment: @chili555 The device is not there yet. I created a "method".

Answer (score 2):

I forked `rtl8812au` driver and added the `2357:010e` device.

Also I added `dkms.conf` to enable DKMS install.

You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS if you are using UEFI, then run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/hanipouspilot/rtl8812au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au
sudo dkms install rtl8812au/0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04.1 the following worked perfectly for TP-Link T4UH ac1200 usb 3.0: https://askubuntu.com/a/1069805/389523

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

then restart the computer, the receiver light should start blinking.

as it is a laptop, one should also disable the internal Wifi:
you can look for the wifi kernel driver with:

```
lspci -nnk
```

then

```
sudo modprobe -r *the name of the internal wifi kernel driver*
```

in my case:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```