# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and TP-Link T4UH

Tags: networking, gnome, 17.04, lsusb

Since today my USB Dongle for WIFI does not work anymore. My kernel is 4.10.0-38 and my OS Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

`lsusb` output does not show the device on any USB Port - yes I tested the port with a normal USB Stick - they are working fine.

The dongle seems to work fine too, since I dual boot with Win7 and that system has an Internet connection via the dongle.

Any ideas why something like this can happen from one day to another? Should I post a log or something?

`lsusb` shows

```
[2357:010e]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb with the device inserted.

Comment: It shows the above number - I currently cant access my desktop PC - otherwise I would show the full output. Tho i think only this is for intrest

Comment: It uses the driver rtl8812au. Did it work previously? Did you download a file and compile it?

Comment: Yes - it worked before. I used this Answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/929265/how-to-install-tp-link-t4uh-drivers-2357010e

Comment: sudo lshw -C network gives me a weird name for the adapter - wlxd46e0eeb9ab6

Comment: I get the Options now and I can see the networks, but with the right password I cannot access the AP/Router. The password is pretty simple - no typos.

Comment: All other devices work fine, an other ubuntu 17.04 notebook as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this just happend now, but this fixed my problem.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and add these lines

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Apperently my mac-adresse was changing constantly, which is a known 17.04 bug.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working.

Comment: @chili555 thanks for the help. Something is still of with the Archer T4HU - this moring it did not work again - plugging in the old USB Stick worked right away. I might return the new one...