# No wifi-adapter found in gnome-control-center?

Tags: wireless

The USB wifi adapter appears here:

```
$ lsusb | grep TP
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:010e TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
```

I had this working before an upgrade to 19.10. I've tried reinstalling the drivers but have not yet been able to get this working yet.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

What are my next steps? I've been going through a lot of the old debug posts but nothing has worked yet.

```
$ iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

br-3ce68697cec1  no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

And I guess if there are any known issues where you need to disconnect the wired connection to even test wifi that would be important to know.

Comment: do you have wired internet available to install wireless drivers? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have wired. And I think I have installed the correct drivers (same ones as for Ubuntu 18.04). I rebuilt them too but filesize was the same.

Comment: I have just posted an answer, let us know if you run into any issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct driver for your V2 device 2357:010e is rtl8812au. The module aliases for 8188eu do not include your device.

Please do:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m 8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: This gets a lot further but I see this error in the final step: 

$ sudo modprobe 8812au
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error

Comment: Maybe this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1541743

Comment: I'm currently going to try to dkms uninstall things first.

Comment: Holy smokes. After dkms removing ALL wireless modules and reinstalling I see it showing in iwconfig. Probably just a bit more faffing to get that showing in the network manager!

Comment: Working now, will edit your post to put the complete steps in.

Comment: It is not necessary to remove the dkms modules for 8188eu. My solution works either way. There is certainly nothing wrong with removing 8188eu if you are tidy.

Comment: how to choose versoin?

Comment: The version of which? 8812au? Please clarify. Is this related to your new question?

Comment: I mean should we be manually choosing the version? I am a bit confused as the git project has a README that says to do one thing (some auto install script) and here we are saying do some shadow workflow thing that is not in the docs.

Comment: Please notice at the git that the README and the dkms process were changed 4 months ago; that is, well after I posted the answer above. Things change and in this case, for the better. The newer process is much smoother.

Comment: ah I see. Thanks this useful context. So I think it look like the original post maybe made it into the repo :) at least in one form or another.

Answer (score 1):

For your TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 (ID: 2357:010e), you could install wireless drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/hanipouspilot/rtl8812au`

Steps to install the drivers:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/hanipouspilot/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au
sudo dkms install rtl8812au/0.1
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Comment: I tried this an no change so far. Did a full reboot.

Comment: Just tried that and tried to revert to wicd but no luck so far.

Comment: Tried but a lot of those commands are not correct. For example: sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8188eu

I think you need to cd into the dir and make all make install etc. That hasn't fixed it yet.

Comment: @mathtick From this answer `https://askubuntu.com/a/952758` by "Pilot6" I just found that `2357:010e` device was not included in the GitHub repo I mentioned earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I market the other answer correct but possibly this one was already working. Key difference seemed to be dkms remove all modules first. I didn't test the repo again once I did that.