# How can I keep TPLink wifi adapter working?

Tags: wireless

I generally manage to get my TP link wifi adapter working, but then after several months later and probably a reboot, it suddenly stops working and I have to refer to my notes, debug, head back to ask ubuntu etc.

Are there any strategies for stopping this endless cycle? Or at least understanding WHY it stops working? Probably an update kills it?

UPDATE: status AFTER fixing things

```
dkms status

$ dkms status
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.10, 5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.10, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.10, 5.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit to include the steps you use to fix the issue and a link to the source code used

Comment: If you install drivers proerly (with dkms), you won't have to re-install them after each kernel upgrade.

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224074/no-wifi-adapter-found-in-gnome-control-center/1225019?noredirect=1#comment2228299_1225019

Comment: @Pilot6 I have used dkms afaik. I use a git repo and run some dkms installer. It is supposed to trigger on upgrade. But something appears to be wrong. I saw multiple version via dkms status, I don't think that usually causes problems but who knows.

Comment: So I basically removed everything related in dkms and rerun the installer but after git pulling the rtl8812au repo, then running sudo make dkms_install ... then rebooting. I did a lot of things but I think removing ALL the dkms status stuff was needed as well as pulling the latest master branch. I am expecting dkms to handle the updates on kernel upgrades but not sure what is happening.

Comment: You may have multiple versions installed using dkms that might cause conflicts, edit the question to include results for 'dkms status`

Comment: @Jeremy31 There is this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224074/no-wifi-adapter-found-in-gnome-control-center/1225019?noredirect=1#comment2228316_1225019 which is about how to fix it. I am wondering how to avoid this ever happening again, maybe by running a check and cleanup script periodically? The fix always seems to be uninstall everything and reinstall latest from the repo and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Lets get everything cleared out

```
sudo dkms remove -m 8812au -v 4.2.2 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/8812au-4.2.2
rm -rf ~/rtl8812au
```

Hopefully there are no rtl8812au or 8812au entries in `dkms status` Then do

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
make clean
sudo dkms_install
```

Reboot

Comment: But how would you know that is the correct version? I mean if you want to automate something to be future proof? I guess we have to script something to scrape the version? Is it really this crazy?

Comment: I can find nothing wrong with that repo that would cause issues with kernel updates unless a user did a `make` and `sudo make install` or used the install script before adding it as dkms.  I know there are issues with the rtl8812au-dkms package in the repos that break dkms, but you haven't posted results for `dkms status`

Comment: Yeah, I am guessing it is some corner case. Will post dkms status for what it's worth but this is after wiping it and getting it working again.